Python Auto-py-to-exe
Good evening,
How to do unbuffered output for my python code using auto-py-to-exe?
I'm trying to unbuffered my python code via auto-py-to-exe, however I failed to do it. i tried to insert to the advanced option within auto-py-to-exe, but I am also getting errors there.
I will be happy for your help!
Thanks in advance!

"im trying to unbuffer my python code" ...  you will need to post said code to the page so someone can review it (in text form not a picture mind you).  You are getting errors?  Also post those in text form so someone can even start to guess.

Provide some personal experience.

installed: in cmd keyin "pip install auto-py-to-exe"
run: in cmd keyin "auto-py-to-exe"
pip list to check verison
example: auto-py-to-exe  2.10.0
pyinstaller     4.5.1
operation the UI. demo like: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

note:

Onefile: Which one to choose depends on your needs.
I use "One Directory", it need to find .exe in the folds.
Console Window (early testing debug):
Recommended for early testing use "Console Based",
because when error occur, the error message can be showed on the console.
like "ModuleNotFoundError", you need pip install requests.
if already installed, you need to UI Advanced:"--hidden-import"
to add the ModuleName. (this is importance, and maybe try many loops)
enter image description here
xgboost is the spacial tool,
it need also in UI Other: "--collect-all", to add the xgboost name
enter image description here
Console Window (normal operation)
Recommended to set "Windowed Based (hide the console)"
if your project have other fold or files,
you need to add in UI Additional Files, to choose the same fold or files.
auto-py-to-exe Specific Options
is output .exe path
you can export .jon file to save the setting.
when next time can be re import it.

